# Time that appium takes to run a test

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, appium

I'm new to Appium and I would like to know about the time that it takes to run a test.

This is my scenario:

- Real device;
- My test case: Steps to answer 16 questions (changing the question by clicking on a button) and checking the results.

It is taking about 160 seconds to run each test. Is this a normal execution time?
I think that it could be minimized if I use "noReset" = true and "fullReset" = false. Am I wrong?

My code:

```
public class AndroidSetup {

AndroidDriver driver;   

public void setConfig() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{

    File appPath = new File("C:\\app\\p");
    File appFile = new File(appPath, "App_1.0.apk");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","0424618914");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");


    capabilities.setCapability("noReset", "true"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("fullReset", "False");*/     


    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appFile.getAbsolutePath());

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);  

}

public class TestCases extends AndroidSetup {

    String app_package_name = "br.name.name_:id/";
    String start_button_id = "btnStart";
    String next_button_id = "btnNext";
    String value_1_id = "radioButton1";
    String value_2_id = "radioButton2";
    String value_3_id = "radioButton3";
    String value_4_id = "radioButton4";
    String value_5_id = "radioButton5";
    String value_6_id = "radioButton6";
    String value_7_id = "radioButton7";
    String value_na_id = "radioButton8";
    String overall_value = "overwall";
    String sys_qual_value = "sysQual";
    String info_qual_value = "infoQual";
    String int_qual_value = "intQual";

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception{       

    setConfig();

} 

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception{
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void Scenario001() throws Exception{

    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + start_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + value_1_id)).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + next_button_id)).click();   


    assertEquals("1,00", driver.findElement(By.id(app_package_name + sys_qual_value)).getText());

}
```

Comment: No it doesn't seem to be. Could share the logs and your scripts executing the tests.

Comment: The log is too long. How can I send?

Comment: try and filter out relevant stuff to share. some debugging should be required.

Comment: I check the log and I could not find anything relevant. Do you have some tips?

Comment: Look at any WAIT you might have introduced and Thread.sleep if any as well.

Comment: I'm not using any wait or theread.sleep. I check the time that the server took to start and it was 90 sec. It is too long, right?

Comment: Depends on the configurations actually, can't comment without the overview of the code.

Comment: I edited my question and added my code. Could you check, please?